# How to implement One To Many (Polymorphic) in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, polymorphism

Hi I have three entities `User`, `Admin`, `Log`
Both the admin and user have many logs.
Each log has one owner might be `User`might be `Admin`.

In this case, I was searching for a similar system as `Laravel Elequent One To Many (Polymorphic)` in `Symfony Doctrine` to implement.

However, I don't want to make each `AdminLog` or `UserLog` extend `Log`
Or use the `ManyToMany` method.

In Laravel we use `morphTo` and `morph` in migrations to declare an entity polymorphic.

I tried `logable_type` and `logable_id` in the `Admin` and `User` entities to simulate that

> **I want s similar mechanic in Symfony however if there better solution or
> way or it's just not the best practice for let me know which is better**

Comment: @skuti i picked up you from top users can you help ?

Comment: @leroy i picked up you from top users can you help ?

Comment: hello so, you dont want to extend or use ManyToMany relation , what about implementing interface can we work with this or you don't want either extend or implement

Comment: @ChafikKerboute Hi the only thing matters for me is the table structure that both user and admin logs stores in same table

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is implement an interface on your **User** and your **Admin** classes.

**Interface**:

```
interface LoggerInterface
{

}
```

**Admin** and **User** classes:

```
#[ORM\Entity()]
class User implements LoggerInterface

#[ORM\Entity()]
class Admin implements LoggerInterface
```

And in your **Log** class you can simply make a **OneToMany** relation to **LoggerInterface** class.

```
#[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: LoggerInterface::class, inversedBy: 'log')]
private LoggerInterface $target;
```

and in your **Admin** and **User** classes:

```
#[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'target', targetEntity: Log::class)]
private Log $log;
```

Comment: What would the Table Structure looks like  ?

Comment: I don't really understand your question, but you would have one Log table, one User table and one Admin table.

Comment: Both User and Admin logs will be stored in the same Log table if that is your question.